# Regular expression to validate image

Tags: regex, image, validation, go

I am writing a web application in golang. I am using regular expression to validate the URL. But I am not able to validate image (abc.png) in the URL validation.

```
var validPath = regexp.MustCompile("^/$|/(home|about|badge)/(|[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$")
```

The above URL takes `/home/`, `/about/` but could not make for `/abc.png`. I mean `.` itself not working

I tried the following regex, but it didn't help

```
var validPath = regexp.MustCompile("^/$|/(home|about|badge|.)/(|[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$")
var validPath = regexp.MustCompile("^/$|/(home|about|badge)(/|.)(|[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$")
```

And I am trying to match http://localhost:8080/badge.png

Could anyone please help me on this?

Comment: You dont allow a point anywhere. You could put the point inside the character class. Also I am not sure about the placement of the last pipe relative to the parentheses.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Please, write some examples that the Regex must match. By the way, why are you using 2 "$"? The end of the string must appear only once.

Comment: @LarsFischer - I updated the question with what I tried. But it didn't help

Comment: @developer033 -  I updated with matching string.

Comment: I thought you want to match something like that. Take a look http://rubular.com/r/Hi5xVkbDOD. Is it right?

Comment: @developer033 -  Thanks. But it is not working for `/home`. I want it to be flexible

Comment: See [this demo](https://play.golang.org/p/66iHN29UQc). Looks like `^/$|^(?:/(home|about|badge))?/((?:badge|abc)\.png|[a-zA-Z0-9]*)$` should work for you. Please let me know.

Comment: This works as expected. Is it possible to parse /about/abc.png with this?
also /badge.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears

```
^/$|^(?:/(home|about|badge))?/((?:badge|abc)\.png|[a-zA-Z0-9]*)$
```

should work for you. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eY1yW5/2).

The pattern breakdown:

- `^/$` - a `/` as a whole string
- `|` - or...
- `^` - start of string
- `(?:/(home|about|badge))?` - optional sequence of `/` + either `home`, or `about` or `badge`
- `/` - a `/` symbol followed with
- `((?:badge|abc)\.png|[a-zA-Z0-9]*)` - Group 1 capturing:

  - `(?:badge|abc)\.png` - `badge` or `abc` followed with `.png`
  - `|` - or...
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` - zero or more alphanumerics
- `$` - end of string

And here is the [Go playground demo](https://play.golang.org/p/66iHN29UQc).

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "regexp"

func main() {
    //var validPath = regexp.MustCompile("^/((home|about)(/[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?|[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.[a-z]+)?$")
    var validPath = regexp.MustCompile(`^/$|^(?:/(home|about|badge))?/((?:badge|abc)\.png|[a-zA-Z0-9]*)$`)

    fmt.Println(validPath.MatchString("/"), validPath.MatchString("/home/"), validPath.MatchString("/about/"), validPath.MatchString("/home/13jia0"), validPath.MatchString("/about/1jnmjan"), validPath.MatchString("/badge.png"), validPath.MatchString("/abc.png"))
    fmt.Println(validPath.MatchString("/nope/"), validPath.MatchString("/invalid.png"), validPath.MatchString("/test/test"))

    m := validPath.FindStringSubmatch("/about/global")
    fmt.Println("validate() :: URL validation path m[1] : ", m[1])
    fmt.Println("validate() :: URL validation path m[2] : ", m[2])
    if m == nil || m[2] != "global" {
        fmt.Println("Not valid")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the following (based off the example paths you posted):

```
var validPath = regexp.MustCompile("^/((home|about)(/[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?|[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.[a-z]+)?$")
```

[Playground with examples](https://play.golang.org/p/4zSZAudqhN)

Comment: Thanks. It closely matches with my requirement. But I am also trying to match abc.png along with batch.png. I tried the following in your goplay. But it is not working. Could you suggest me how to do that?


`var validPath = regexp.MustCompile("^/((home|about)(/?[a-zA-Z0-9]*)(|badge|abc)\\.png)?$")`

Comment: Updated my answer to support that.

Comment: (or did you just mean to support **specifically** badge.png and abc.png, and not meant to allow any other picture?)

Comment: You are right specifically abc.png | badge.png. Also I am trying to get the string after about. For example /about/global

`  m := validPath.FindStringSubmatch(r.URL.Path)
  log.Printf("validate() :: URL validation path m[2] : ", m[2])
  if m == nil {
   http.NotFound(w, r)
   return
  }`
It is not taking m[2] = global.

Comment: Hell, that looks like a lot of unnecessary work. Haven't you heard about [httprouter](https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter)?

Comment: Ugh. I never heard about this. Yeah I can try that. Again that's lot of work. Application has lot of handlers. For now I have to stick with this :(

Answer (score 0):

You can validate with the following Regex:

```
var validPath = regexp.MustCompile("^\/(home|about|badge)\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+[.][a-z]+$")
```

Ps: I made a flexible Regex, so it accepts a lot of formats of images: `png`, `jpg`, `jpeg` and so on..

You can test it here: [Regex](http://rubular.com/r/17W82gABii)